# Postgresql select from view by date range but no date field is present

Tags: postgresql, date, range

I have schedule table that save some events in DB.

for example:

```
**event_tab**
event_id
day
time_start
time_end
```

One record represents one event that can be repeated weekly. Column day can have values from 1-7 where 1 is monday.
I would like to pass to view range of dates, for example: 2016-06-01 to 2016-06-30 and that should generate that rows (events) that fit that arguments.

I don't know how to generate rows for that query.

Comment: that time range is for time_start or time_end?..

Comment: @VaoTsun time_start and time_end is hour for example event start at: 12:00 and end at 14:00

Comment: day is `dow`, time_start and time_end are `time` without date, so how you want db to guess what date was when event happened?..